How to use sqlRestriction after Hibernate 6 Upgrade
We are currently using Hibernate 5. We had code like below
Criteria query;
query.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(....)
Now while migration to Hibernate 6 how do we replace this as sqlRestriction support seems missing in Hibernate 6
Not getting any solution
